# Forwarding tap from child view to parent?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewA->UICollectionViewCell->UICollectionViewB` view hierarchy.

When I tap into `UICollectioinViewB` (that sits inside the cell, yellow colored) the tap doesn't seem to be forwarded to it's parent `UICollectionViewCell`.

What would be the best way to forward that touch to it's parent?

[image: View Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to capture the tap for UICollectionViewB, then disable its `User Interaction Enabled` setting on the identity inspector in Interface Builder.

Comment: Hey Marcus, thanks for the reply... right now I don't really need to capture it... but I may need to do so in the future, any ideas?